# How to get an option from select box in rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to ask that how can i get the selected option in my controller action in rails, so that i can save it in database. I don't want to use rails helper for select-box and options. As i have copied the select box code, and it has large number of options. I hope my question is clear enough.
I am using form_for helper though.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have code like this:

```
form_for @variable do |f|
    f.select --------------
end
```

You'll want to catch the params & save them, like this:

```
def new 
   @variable = Model.new
end

def create
   @variable = Model.new(post_params)
   @variable.save
end

private
def post_params
    params.require(:variable).permit(:select_name)
end
```

Just realized you're using Rails 3. My code is for Rails 4, but the process remains the same -- treat the select box as any other input, and to do that you have to ensure it's called from the form_for function

---

If you want to create a country select box, you could use the [`country_select gem`](https://github.com/rails/country_select) with this code in your form_for:

```
<%= f.country_select :country, ["United States"] %> #Can write any default country
```

This will keep it consistent with Rails

Comment: Can i use form_for and inside it use simple html select-box with options? Instead of f.select_box?

Comment: Maybe - the whole point of form_for is that it creates a form with pre-formatted "name" tags (which are passed to the controller as params). Typically, these names will be "variable[input_name]", which keeps with Rails' model of being modular. A hack you could use is to just call the select box a variation of the other form names & just put it into the form. May I ask what options you need in the select box? They're actually very versatile - perhaps I could create some code to make the right select box for you?

Comment: It is a long country select box, it has more than 200 options in it :(

Comment: Can i get values from form in rails without using form_helper? by using <form> </form> instead of form_helper?

Comment: I am not entirely sure to be honest. There are 2 things which Rails needs - an authentication token & the params variable (defined by the form's name properties). I imagine it could be done, but it's much, much better to keep with Rails standards. May I ask why you'd want a naked HTML form in the app? If there's a special reason, we can work to remedy it

Comment: Okay, it looks like you *might* be able to do it with naked HTML forms as per this discussion [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17096055/how-to-create-embeddable-html-form-from-a-rails-application) . If you put your code into your question, I'll see if I can make a working form for you (fingers crossed!)

Comment: It is because i have copy pasted a large code, and i don't want to edit it as it will take too long.

Comment: Paste it into your answer or a chat & I'll edit it for you then! An application is a _system_, which means that if you get it right now, you'll be able to continually use it. The trick is to make it dependable :)